# How to determine if 2 URIs (paths) belong to the same partition or volume

Tags: c++, linux, windows, c++14

Question in 2 steps. In C++14 (or C), under Linux and under Windows.

1. Is there a way to identify (UUID) the disk partition (or docker volume) which is storing a given URI (file or directory)?
2. Is there a way to know if 2 URIs (files of dirs) are stored on the same disk partition (or docker volume)?

(to avoid a X Y problem: ) The real goal is to be able to move files with the best method:

- light move if they are on the same partition (or Docker volume),
- content copy if they are on different partitions.

I have this tracks: statvfs, GetVolumeInformationByHandleW.

Comment: "*The real goal is to be able to move files with the best method*" - then let the OS handle it for you. On Windows, you can use `MoveFileEx()` with the `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED` flag. It will do an efficient move on the same drive, and a copy+delete across drives.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, this is straightforward:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
struct stat A, B;

stat( "/etc/fstab", &A );
stat( "/boot/grub2/grub.cfg", &B );

if( A.st_dev == B.st_dev ) {
    /* Files are on same device, shallow processing is OK */
} else {
    /* Files are on different devices, bytes gotta be moved */
}
```